# Will my undergrad thesis be considered for my Master's admission given that my areas of interest has changed a bit?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

During my undergrad, I published a paper on a topic relating to Natural Language Processing since I was fond of learning algorithms. I wish to pursue a Master's degree in Artificial Intelligence and Computer Graphics. 
Does the paper that I published during my undergrad still be considered by an admission committee, at least for my research skills that I have been able to demonstrate? Given that the area in which I wish to pursue my Master's is fairly different from my undergrad thesis.

Comment: Add it as part of your Resume/CV and you can discuss it in your SOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s fairly widely understood that people’s research interests can evolve over time, particularly in the transition from undergraduate to graduate. So, yes, the committee will consider your undergrad paper, precisely because it shows potential for research, even if it’s not in the field you want to study in the graduate program.

You should, however, be sure to make an *affirmative* argument for your new field of study in your statement of purpose: talk about why you’re gravitating *toward* the new field, not away from the old one.

Comment: Your answer will be really helpful. Thank you so much! :)